# Joints of my model sway in gazebo

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, the joints of my robot model start to sway when I spawn it in gazebo and then launch its controllers I added previously.
Here is the contents of my yaml file:

> cambot:   # Publish all joint states
> -----------------------------------   joint_state_controller:
> type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
> publish_rate: 50
> # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------   tilt_position_controller:
>
> ```
> type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
> joint: tilt
> pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}   pan_position_controller:
> type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
> joint: pan
> pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}   lift_position_controller:
> type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
> joint: lift
> pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
> ```

And this is the contents of my launch file:

> file="$(find
> cambot_description)/config/cambot_control.yaml"
> command="load"/>

What am I supposed to do to avoid the sway situation mentioned above?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286658/joints-of-my-model-sway-in-gazebo/) by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You first probably want to tweak the controller PID parameters. This can be done at runtime using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure). I'd recommend dropping i and d gains to 0 and first adjusting p only. In most cases this adjustment is sufficient to make the robot "behave".

If your robot is hard to simulate correctly (for instance if it has very different masses/inertias of different links), then you might want to look at some other things to tweak as discussed [in this Q/A](https://answers.ros.org/question/216092/problem-with-the-robot-model-collapsing/) and the links provided there.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-27**:
Really appreciate your advice, sir. I do fix the problem by modifying the pid gains (even though I still can't comprehend the concept of pid).